# Django: Best practice to sum all total amounts based on a model field

Tags: python, django

Here is my code

```py
reports: queryset
    for reports in reports:
        data.append(DataModel(
            model_id=report.num,
            title=report.title,
            total_price=report.total_amount,
        ))
```

This code will create some DataModel objects and will append the object into a list.
I want to sum `total_price` of all the objects with the same `obj.id`.

For example:
If we have these objects on the queryset:

1. id:obj1 total_price: 10
2. id:obj3 total_price: 20
3. id:obj2 total_price: 30
4. id:obj1 total_price: 40
5. id:obj2 total_price: 50

In the list I want to have these object in the list:

1. id:obj1 total_price: 50
2. id:obj3 total_price: 20
3. id:obj2 total_price: 80

What is the best practice to do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
Model.objects.all().values("group_by_field").annotate(all_qty=Sum("total_price"))
```

Comment: Thanks but the 'annotate' will have some costs and this will do some queries to the database. I prefer to have another way without of this cost

Comment: @MehdiAria annotate is the shortest way I guess and optimized as well. maybe! someone will provide better solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not immediately obvious how you can do it without looping through twice. The assumption here is that reports with the same model id will share the same title, otherwise you may need to concatenate them when you add the total_amounts.

```
reports: queryset

totals_dict = {}
for report in reports:
    #loop through to check for multiple amounts, storing results in dict
    #using report_num as key 
    if report.num in totals_dict:
        totals_dict[report.num][1] += report.total_amount
    else:
        totals_dict.setdefault(report.num, []).append(report.title)
        totals_dict[report.num].append(report.total_amount)
 #create data list using dict 
 for key, var in totals_dict.items():
     data.append(DataModel(
         model_id=key,
         title=var[0],
         total_price=var[1],
     ))
```

Comment: I guess there are many mistakes here, where did you define `my_dict`? why the result is saved in a dictionary instead of a list? (the result should be a list of objects) why you didn't use the `data` list at all?

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood, thinking you wanted to keep your original data list.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Another mistake, You should use `for key, var in totals_dict.items():`

Comment: Is this possible to do that single loop?

Comment: If you are creating a list, it's tricky to identify previous elements in a list that need updating, which is why there are two loops and the first uses a dict with keys. If the queryset is ordered, say,  to group id:obj1 values together, then you might be able to do it by checking for a changed value and creating the DataModel when it changes, but I don't have enough info about the queryset to say.